# How can I avoid moving out of a borrow when removing values from a borrowed Vec?

Tags: vector, rust

I have a struct that does not implement `Clone` or `Copy`:

```
struct MyStruct {
    data: Vec<MyData>,
}
```

I'd like to write a function on the struct that "cleans up" data that's no longer valid:

```
fn clean_up(&mut self) {
    self.data = self.data.into_iter()
      .filter(|data| data.is_still_valid())
      .collect()
}
```

This doesn't work, the compiler complains that I'm moving out of a borrowed context when I use `into_iter`. Without `into_iter`, it fails because I'm creating a `Vec` of `&MyData`, not `MyData`.

I can fix this by writing something like the following instead, but it is far less readable:

```
let mut invalid_indicies = vec![];
for (i, data) in self.data.iter().enumerate() {
    if !data.is_still_valid() {
        invalid_indicies.push(i);
    }
}
for i in invalid_indicies {
    self.data.remove(i);
}
```

Is it possible to use `filter` and similar sequence operators to modify vectors owned by a struct while still borrowing instead of moving `self` in `clean_up()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) to remove items from the vector in place:

```
fn clean_up(&mut self) {
    self.data.retain(|data| data.is_still_valid());
}
```

Comment: This answer works in the specific use-case of a `Vec`. In the more general case, (e.g. when using a container that does not have an equivalent for `Vec::retain`), then you can use [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.swap.html) to take the data out of `self` before filtering it and putting it back in. [Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=9bc30ef65308fba88b98b588bdc50c62).